# What specific foods and drinks are forbidden by the LDS (Mormon) Church?

Tags: lds, religious-practice, diet

I understand that members of the LDS (Mormon) Church are prohibited from drinking coffee and perhaps some other drinks and possibly food, much like the Jewish people in the Old Testament were forbidden from eating pork and other foods.

What are the specific drinks that are forbidden by the LDS Church today?  Also, are there any specific foods that are forbidden as well?  What is the basis for these teachings in the Bible and other sources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Word of Wisdom refers both to Doctrine and Covenants section 89, and also to its interpretation. The scripture is listed here:

http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/89?lang=eng

As with many issues in LDS doctrine, some aspects are specified, and others are left open-ended. The official list from mormon.org posted above contains a few items that are explicitly banned--you can't claim to be "living the Word of Wisdom" (and be considered worthy of a temple recommend) if you consume them, even occasionally. However, the scripture contains other guidelines whose interpretation is open to debate within the LDS community. In addition to caffeine (discussed elsewhere), the following is debated:

> Yea, flesh also of beasts and of the fowls of the air, I, the Lord,
>   have ordained for the use of man with thanksgiving; nevertheless they
>   are to be used sparingly; And it is pleasing unto me that they should
>   not be used, only in times of winter, or of cold, or famine.

Within the LDS community, someone on a pure meat diet would not be ineligible to receive a temple recommend, but personal opinions vary widely on how this should be interpreted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Does hot drinks include hot water, hot tea, and hot apple cider?  Anything hot?

Comment: @Narnian, the only "hot drinks" that are included in the official (minimalist) interpretation are coffee and tea (but not herbal tea). Under the assumption that the phrase "hot drinks" referred to the popular hot drinks of the time, most mormons don't interpret the scripture as referring to temperature.

Comment: @amcnabb. So what about iced tea?

Comment: @TRiG, iced tea is still tea, and as I mentioned earlier, it's not about temperature.

Answer (score 10):

[From Mormon.org](http://mormon.org/faq/law-of-health/):

> Our body is a precious gift from God. To help keep our bodies and our
> minds healthy and strong, God gave a law of health to Joseph Smith in
> 1833. This law is known as the Word of Wisdom (see Doctrine and Covenants 89:1-21).
>
> In addition to emphasizing the benefits of proper eating and physical
> and spiritual health, God has spoken against the use of:
>
> - Tobacco.
> - Alcohol.
> - Coffee and tea.
> - Illegal drugs.
>
> God promises great physical and spiritual blessings to those who
> follow the Word of Wisdom. Today, the scientific community promotes
> some of the same principles that a loving God gave to Joseph Smith
> nearly two centuries ago.

Reading the comments on the site linked above, the reasoning for the prohibition of these substances is that they impair the clear use of the mind; this is essentially the same principle why drunkenness is forbidden in Catholic moral teaching: free will and intelligence are gifts from God which allow us to know and love Him, so the voluntary impairment of these is wrong. St. Thomas Aquinas, on the question of how much are we allowed to drink, answers that we can drink "to the point of merriment (also translated as 'hilarity')."

Comment: There was an edit (I've cancelled it) proposing that "caffeine" be removed from the list. I don't know the veracity of this... just noting: caffeine has been questioned

Comment: @MarcGravell From the Mormons I have talked to caffeine is a debate even in their culture. It is allowed officially, but considered a drug/addictive substance and should be avoided as such. I have known active Mormons on both sides, some that drink soda with it and Mormons that refuse.

Comment: @MaskedPlant sure, I understand; hence I didn't want to "approve" the edit, but I also didn't want the fact that it had been questioned lost into the ether

Comment: So if it's more correct to edit out caffeine, then why are coffee and tea banned? If I understand correctly that the underlying principle is that you're not to take anything that clouds the ability of the mind then what is it about coffee and tea that is mind altering?  I ask both out of comparative-religious curiosity and because I get the impression there might be some "good" coffee and tea that heretofore I've not known about.  :-)

Comment: @AudioSancto It was explained to me as because they are addictive, not just mind altering, and my Mormon friends will drink herbal tea so I think there is a line drawn somewhere there as well.

Comment: Fair enough -- I get the "consume nothing addictive" part... but what is there in coffee that is addictive other than caffeine (or in my case, Kahlua)?

Comment: @Audio: While the church has declined to get into specific scientific details, the exact words of the original revelation are to not consume "hot drinks."  This has been interpreted by church leaders as referring to coffee and tea, which constituted the principal hot drinks at the time the revelation was given.  It should be noted, though, that modern research has found that habitually consuming overly-heated (or overly-chilled, for that matter) beverages can cause serious long-term damage to the tongue, mouth, throat and stomach.  It's possible that that's a factor as well.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Very interesting!  In the movie Saints and Soldiers -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saints_and_Soldiers -- the Mormon protagonist at one point, on a very cold and snowy night, refuses the offer to drink hot coffee, insisting on sticking with his hot lemonade instead. I mention this because the movie was made by a company specializing in entertainment for LDS consumers; if the general prohibition was on hot drinks then this detail slipped by... or can an exception be made for health in cold weather?

Comment: @Audio: As I said, that's a private explanation, given as a possible, speculative interpretation. It's not considered doctrine.

Comment: What is the basis of the "illegal drugs" category?  Is that just a withholding of laws, that many/most Christians follow?  Or is there something more specific there?  I ask simply because what is "illegal" varies widely by locality, so I'm assuming this is a rule against breaking the law, more than against specific drugs.

Comment: @Flimzy Well if a drug is not prescribed to you by a doctor and is not sold over the counter; in the USA, Canada, several European countries and elsewhere then that drug is illegal for you to take. So I don't see how this varies widely, in fact I don't think the drugs a doctor would prescribe even varies that much. The drugs that are available over the counter do vary a little, but not much.

Comment: @MaskedPlant: Many drugs are legally available without a prescription. And even within the realm of prescriptions, those drugs that are "legal" vary; in some localities, greatly.  In Mexico you can get all sorts of drugs OTC that in the U.S. require a prescription. And in many places recreational drugs (marijuana especially) are legal.  Can a Mormon smoke pot in Denmark? Can a Mormon take viagra in Mexico without a prescription?

Comment: @Flimzy I think that would make a great question, I think this conversation has diverted quite a bit from the original topic, and this comment list is getting pretty long.

Comment: @Flimzy - The Articles of Faith states, "12 We believe in being subject to kings, presidents, rulers, and magistrates, in obeying, honoring, and sustaining the law." The Word of Wisdom says, "11 Every herb in the season thereof, and every fruit in the season thereof; all these to be used with prudence and thanksgiving." I think the key word there is "prudence".